# Multiline output in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop, multilinestring

My task is to write a function planning a track run. I have to add a while loop to see if the input parameter a_distance was covered and count the number of laps within this distance. I have the following (yet uncompleted) function defined:

```
import math  # ceil

LAP_DISTANCE = 400

def plan_track_run(a_distance):
    count = 0
    total = 0
    r_output = ""

    while total < a_distance:
        count = count + (1/(LAP_DISTANCE)*a_distance)
        total = total + count * LAP_DISTANCE
        r_output += f"lap #{math.ceil(count)} time ____ s in {count:.2f} x {LAP_DISTANCE}m ={total:.2f}m\n"
```

The output is a template to write down times for particular distances. The output when the a_distance is smaller than a lap distance (400 meters) can be seen here:

```
lap #1 time ____ s in 0.50 x 400m = 200.00m
```

Unfortunately, I do not achieve the desired output in the case when the a_distance is larger than a lap distance, e.g. 1500 meters. There should be a multiline output for each laps, counting upwards until the total number of laps and the total distance is displayed in the last line:

```
lap #1 time ____ s in 1.00 x 400m = 400.00m
lap #2 time ____ s in 2.00 x 400m = 800.00m
lap #3 time ____ s in 3.00 x 400m = 1200.00m
lap #4 time ____ s in 3.75 x 400m = 1500.00m
```

My current and wrong output for a_distance = 1500 is:

```
lap #4 time ____ s in 3.75 x 400m = 1500.00m
```

Please help me modify this code so that I achieve the desired output also for distances larger than 400 meters. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of language it is?

Comment: @Justinas looks like python (but there is no tag, so this is only an educated guess)

Comment: It's unclear what your current output and your expected/desired output is. Which input to the function generates the wrong output?

Comment: Why write something convoluted such as `(1/(LAP_DISTANCE)*a_distance)` instead of a simple `a_distance/LAP_DISTANCE`?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new to Python and this forum, I edited the post with the Python hashtag and put the desired and obtained output there.

Comment: @M.J. you show the "current and wrong output", but the fuller block above contains the same line already. What would the correct output be? According to my book 3.75*400 _is_ 1500, so what is wrong about that output?

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear.  A distance of 1500 consists of 3.75 laps. The output for 1500 should therefore consist of 4 lines like in the wished output,  not just of 1 line for all laps.

Comment: Always a good read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
LAP_DISTANCE = 400
a_distance = 1500
count = count + (1/(LAP_DISTANCE)*a_distance) # 0 + 1/400*1500 = 3.75
total = total + count * LAP_DISTANCE # 0 + 3.75 * 400 = 1500
```

Your second formula fully cancels out the first one, leaving you with `total == a_distance` which will terminate the loop.

Why do you need to calculate the count from the distance? Just `count = count + 1` should be enough, no? And honestly, I would rename that to `lap` to give it proper context.

The next total would be `total = total + LAP_DISTANCE` or `total = count * LAP_DISTANCE`. You should either build the cumulative sum or multiply to get the total, but not both at the same time. To avoid overshooting the distance, a simple conditional or `math.min` can be used.

Alternatively, compute the number of laps first (`laps = math.ceil(a_distance/LAP_DISTANCE)`) and then execute the loop laps times: `for lap in range(laps): ...`

Comment: Count is to count the number of laps within a_distance. If I have let's say a_distance = 500 m, then there are (1/400) * 500 = 1,25 laps. 
For examples like these, there should be a line for each completed lap and if there are not fully completed laps such as in this case (1 lap, 0.25 lap).  In each line, the {count:.2f} and the {total:.2f} should add up: 

lap #1 time ____ s in 1.00 x 400m = 400.00m
lap #2 time ____ s in 1.25 x 400m = 500.00 m

Comment: Another example: a_distance = 1200 m 
- This distance consists of (1200/400) = 3 laps which is calculated with the computation in the count variable. 
- Here, the output should be: 

lap #1 time ____ s in 1.00 x 400m = 400.00m
lap #2 time ____ s in 2.00 x 400m = 800.00m
lap #3 time ____ s in 3.00 x 400m = 1200.00m

I would just like to modify the code so that this output is obtained when a_distance > LAP_DISTANCE.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, this is an assignment which states explicitely that I have to use the while loop. With the for loop it works for me.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to do the computation in the while loop with the count variable in the loop? So that for every 400 meters in the a_distance, it adds 1 to count. If there is an incomplete lap, e.g. which is for 1500, the rest is added.

Comment: Iteration example:
For example if the a_distance = 1400, there are 3,5 laps (3 * 400 + 0,5 *400). 
The variable names are in the brackets (). 
Condition: While 0 (total distance covered) < 1200 (a_distance)    True
 - count = 0 + 1 (1st lap covered)   -> count = 1
 - total = 0 + 400 (distance in 1st lap covered)  -> total = 400
Condition: While 400 (total distance covered so far) < 1200 (a_distance) True
 - count = 1 + 1 (2nd lap covered)   - count = 2
 - total = 400 + 400 (2nd lap distance covered) - total = 800

Comment: Condition: While 800 (total distance covered) < 1200 (a_distance) True
 - count = 2 + 1 (3rd lap covered)  - count = 3
 - total = 800 + 400 (3rd lap distance covered) - total = 1200 

Condition: While 1200 (total distance covered) < 1200 FALSE
Loop is finished because the while condition is false.

Comment: @M.J. It's absolutely impossible to read anything from the last 3 comments. You need to fix your arithmetic: use multiplication to get the current value or use addition to get the next value; you cannot combine them. Use `math.min` (or a condition) to handle the last incomplete lap. Count is 3.75 in your first loop iteration